# Dynamic Bootstrap Accordian loads in show

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have a bootstrap accordion that is generated dynamically from code behind. It is loaded during page_init. Everything works except they are all set to open ('show') not closed ('hide').

If I take the generated markup and run it, it works fine so the html is OK. Any ideas?

Thanks

============== EDIT ============

This script resolves the problem

```
Private Sub SectionClose()
    Try
        Dim SB As New StringBuilder
        SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
        SB.Append(" $('#accordion').accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false }); ")
        SB.Append("$('.selector').accordion(); ")
        SB.Append("}); ")
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ShowCollapse", SB.ToString, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim vError As New SendError
        vError.MailError("214", PageName, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

and it now works perfectly, but throws a Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'

This is what the generated markup looks like

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Current Board Members</div>
    <!-- Start of Dynamic elements -->
    <div id="MainContent_ContactBoardMembers" class="panel-body">

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_1">John Doe - Treasurer</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse_1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_2">John Smith - President</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_3">Bill Mathews - Director at large</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse_3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Dynamic elements -->
</div>
```

Edit - added to show how to create accordion from code behind

```
 Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each Row As DataRow In DT.Rows
                i = Row("Member_ID")
                Dim MemberName As String = ""
                MemberName += vFunction.ReturnText(Row("First_Name"))
                MemberName += " " & vFunction.ReturnText(Row("Surname"))
                MemberName += " - " & vFunction.ReturnText(Row("Position"))
                Dim PanelHeading As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
                With PanelHeading
                    .Attributes.Add("class", "panel-heading")
                End With
                Dim H4 As New HtmlGenericControl("h4")
                With H4
                    .Attributes.Add("class", "panel-title")
                End With
                PanelHeading.Controls.Add(H4)
                Dim aData As New HtmlGenericControl("a")
                With aData
                    .Attributes.Add("class", "accordion-toggle collapsed")
                    .Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "collapse")
                    .Attributes.Add("data-parent", "#accordion")
                    .Attributes.Add("href", "#collapse_" & i)
                    ' .Attributes.Add("data-target", "#collapse_" & i)
                    .InnerHtml = MemberName
                End With


                H4.Controls.Add(aData)
```

Comment: Hi,  have created new panels of accordion from JQuery but then controls within newly created panels are not available in code-behind and also looses new panels after post-back. Hence I thought of adding it code-behind. But not sure where to start ! Come across your post while searching. Can you help either on creating it from code-behind or maintaining it on post-back?

Comment: The only way to access them is via JavaScript - see the above sub SectionClose

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I have done it using JS and Ajax POST instead of server event on button. So, I was checking with you, how you created Accordion dynamically from code-behind as I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: I have added a code snippet. Just add everything to one server control that works as a placeholder on the page

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate you taking time to add the snippet. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the 'solution' (adding the script) didn't help and when I added jquery.ui to the page (for some reason it wasn't working in the bundle) the error went, but the issue was still there - I did notice that every time there was a javascript error the accordion worked, so I disabled one script at a time in the masterpage.

The NavBar is built dynamically and a script is loaded to change @media according to how large it is - once I changed .collapse to .navbar-collapse everything worked :-)